# How to execute different sets of data on different browsers in Selenium Web Driver 3.4.0

Tags: selenium

**Context**

I am using Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 in java and using excel file to store our test case and test data to test the web application. However I have successfully done with running the tests with same set of data in different browsers using Testng.xml parameter passing mechanism.

**Problem**

I want to test the web app with different set of test data in different browsers (Chrome,IE and FireFox).

Currently Test Data is stored in an excel file and same test data of each test case runs on each browser sequentially through TestNG. I need to test web app with 3 sets of different data for each of the 3 browsers, so one solution may be that we will have to create 3 columns in excel file named "Test Data for Chrome", "Test Data for Firefox" and "Test Data for IE". But this solution does not seem to be correct to me. If there is any other solution/approach to achieve this in Selenium/TestNG - please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code would be helpful, in order to help you....

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous teams, we had to support more than 40 websites served from a single platform. So the tests, browser and test-data matrix was huge. We solved the problem using annotations and enums. In your case this part:

> same test data of each test case runs on each browser sequentially through TestNG

can be loaded per run, which is mapped to a `BrowserType` enum value and corresponding annotation of the particular test case. This way you need to only store, load and map the data once per test.